# Prove this set is closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I just need to prove that this set
$$E := \left\{ (x, \lambda x): x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{ 0 \}, \lambda \in  \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right\}$$
is closed in $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}) \times (\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\})$ with the usual topology, but i cannot see the way... Just tried to used the definition or arguing by contradiction, but it does not seem to be easy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Show that

$$\hat E := \left\{ (x, \lambda x): x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}, \lambda \in  \mathbb{R} \right\} $$

is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^{2n+2}$, then use the definition of subspace topology.

Comment: Just have done it. Thanks!

Comment: No worries—feel free to accept the answer